# всплытие и перехват js

Tags: javascript

Скажите пожалуйста как сделать так, чтобы вместо event.target.id получать у "li" класс и индекс в коллекции

Вот пример кода :

```js
const list = document.querySelector(".list");
list.addEventListener("click", event => {
  let target =  event.target.id;
  console.log(target);
});
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div id="one" class="item">1</div>
  <div id="two" class="item">2</div>
  <div id="three" class="item">3</div>
  <div id="four" class="item">4</div>
</div>
```

Id тут стоят только для примера!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Причем здесь делегирования я не понял, по вопросу - найти класс и индекс можно вот так:

```js
const list = document.querySelector(".list");
list.addEventListener("click", event => {
  let t = event.target;
  let i = [...list.querySelectorAll('*')].indexOf(t);
  console.log(t.className, i);
});
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `t.parentNode == list`

Comment: @Grundy я не понял :)

Comment: `t` - это `div.item`, родителем этого дива будет `div.list`, в самом начале кода `div.list` сохраняется в переменную `list`, и ему добавляется обработчик события. Таким образом можно не брать `parent`, а сразу обращаться к `list`

Comment: @Grundy ах это, да, так, только в таких ответах я стараюсь не менять код, который напрямую к ответу не относится..., не думаю что это тут существено

Comment: строчки про которую я говорю нет в исходном коде :)

Comment: @Grundy блин, а я только сейчас после 3 раза понял что слушатель один, на листе, я почему-то решил что там querySelectorAll, спасибо, сейчас поправлю

Comment: @Stranger in the Q  А кстати, смотрю, вы в подобных кодах предпочитаете [...elements] - это вопрос вкуса или у него есть какое-то преимущество перед перебором for() ?

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME да мне больше нравится функциональщина

Comment: @Stranger in the Q Спасибо большое за ответ! Отталкиваясь от вашего решение все получилось, но только через цикл, так как такой синтаксис i = [...list] я еще не знаю)